# What is more similar to c#?

Tags: c#

I am not a born programmer. I did my computer engineering and went as system admin.  A friend of mine, recommended me for a programmer job and I begun my life as a C# programmer in June, 2010.

I had difficulties in understanding functions at start  and *"C#"* , the word pronounced like C and I worked out some c problems and Understood the basics.

**I read a article** [Java and C#](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBYQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.25hoursaday.com%2FCsharpVsJava.html&ei=u4H-TI_LK4nmrAehk9D2Bw&usg=AFQjCNEaZqtSFfFoMjFLsOTRJ6UtDkiIZA)

Now , This is the real problem. I dont know even the declaration part in Java programming. If Java is so similar to C#, Is that mean I have to learn Java and Stop learning C. ?? >> Its a great dilemma for me.

I prefer programmers who know Java and C# to answer to this question. I am expecting reasonable answers as I value stack over flow programmersz answer as my final decision :]

Comment: More over i heard Java is free and since c compiler I am using is a trial one and will end soon. Switching to Java will be a wise choise..isnt it ?

Comment: You will never get a straight answer other than "do what you like, or do what you will get paid to do".

Comment: Why would you have to stop learning C# and learn Java instead? You haven't given any reason for why you'd want to do that.

Comment: What? Are you learning C# or C? Why does Java matter if your job is in C#?

Comment: Larry would say Java and Bill would say C#.

Comment: He is saying I think that he is learning C to help him with C#, and he is asking if he should stop that and learn Java instead to help him with C#.  The obvious answer is learn C# itself.

Comment: This should be transferred to programmers.

Comment: @Jon , I am not stopping c# learning, but I am enriching C# knowledge through Java programming.

Comment: @Karthik Ratnam: Microsoft has an Express Edition of Visual Studion for C#. It's free. There is also Mono, if you don't want a Microsoft product. Mono is free. As for the article, it looks like it was originally written in 2001 and updated in 2007, so don't worry too much. Things have changed since then. If your job is for C# then don't learn Java - learn Java when you need it. As for pronouncing it, try it like this: "See Sharp" (the # is pronounced as "Sharp", which is actually a musical symbol).

Comment: @Frustratedwithformsdesinger: Being little experience dont make me little knowledged, I am single handedly taking care of my c# asp.net project in our company. It has more than 10 modules with 200 + forms in it.  I know that C# has an express edition and I dont like mono for some reasons. Other than that , I agree with your point about java article. Cheers.

Comment: @Karthik: So why did you write "Is that mean I have to learn Java and Stop learning C"?

Comment: @Jon I just wrote stop learning c and not C#.  Learning more and more c is only helping me in writing good functions, declaring variables, using pointers in place. If you are the same Jon Skeet, who wrote "C# in Depth", I am very grateful to you already, as I just bought C# 2.0 and 3.0 of your book two weeks ago. You started with generics even in the first chapter, How would just learning C would help me to understand big concepts like Generics. The link I provided in my question quotes Java is having Generics. So learing Java would not be a big step in learning C# quickly and effieciently ??

Comment: @Karthik Ratnam: Generics in Java work differently than in C#. Assuming they work the same may lead to some serious frustration/confusion.

Comment: @Karthik: I assumed you'd just failed to include the "#" given that you hadn't mentioned learning C before. And yes, I'm the author of C# in Depth. C is completely different to C#, and there are big differences between Java and C# too. In particular, generics are completely different. I would just stick with C# if I were you.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Sorry I forgot to mention that I learned C too. Do you know any website links that describe special properties of C# or so. So that I can concentrate on learning that in C#, rather that learning all.

Comment: @ FrustratedWithFormsDesigner : I don't have a in-depth knowledge in generics , so I could not differentiate the two codes and concept behind it :(

Comment: @Karthik: I don't really know what you mean by "special properties" - but if you're happy just learning C#, make sure you have appropriate books. C# in Depth isn't a good beginner book, but hopefully you'll find it useful later. I'd recommend Essential C# or C# 4 in a Nutshell for starters.

Comment: I forgot to mention speacial properties in detail, but I am thinking now that I have to complete these two beginner books first and do a little more programs from Depth till the next July. It would make a experienced programmer with 1 year experience and then come back again and talk with you about special properties. That wont be a problem for you too, isnt it :].

Comment: Thanks for discussing so much detail with me, I am very happy and feeling priveleged to speak with an C# author whom's book from which I am learning and going to learn a lot. :]. If just learing C# , can make a good c# programmer, I wont need any java or c books on my table from tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learning either Java or C# will give you a grounding in the basic skills for a programming job. Once you know one of these languages, learnng the other one will be fairly simple, as there are a lot of similarities.

If you want to know which is "best", then look at the job market and decide where you think the better opportunities or most interesting jobs lie.

Comment: Thanks Jason. I didnt thought Java in par with c#. I thought Java as a language like C from which c# got derived. So  will learning java  make me a good c# programmer?

Comment: @Karthik Ratnam: Learning Java won't necessarily make you a better programmer. But if you learn one language, the other will be easy to pick up. And if you learn both, you will gain insights and skills that you would not get from just one language, so it will help. But don't spread yourself too thin or confuse yourself - learn them one at a time. The real way to become a good programmer is to practice, practice, practice. (Good programmers never stop learning, even after 30 or 40 years at it)